# Incrementing with one query a set of values in a field with UNIQUE constraint, Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have a table in which I have a numeric field **A**, which is set to be **UNIQUE**. This field is used to indicate an order in which some action has to be performed. I want to make an **UPDATE** of all the values that are greater, for example, than **3**. For example,
I have

```
A     
1
2
3
4
5
```

Now, I want to add **1** to all values of **A** greater than **3**. So, the result would be

```
A     
1
2
3
5
6
```

The question is, whether it is possible to be done using only one query? Remember that I have a **UNIQUE** constraint on the column **A**.

Obviously, I tried

```
UPDATE my_table SET A = A + 1 WHERE A > 3;
```

but it did not work as I have the constraint on this field.

Comment: Previous asked here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674644/database-update-order  In short, can you drop the constraint and add it back when finished?

Comment: Removing the constraint is not an option here. If I wanted to do so I would probably use a simple procedure and update the values in a specified order so I would omit a duplicate key issue.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a new idea, based on a partial unique index. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: I will answer it when I will be able to check how it works for my problem. That will be probably tomorrow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### PostgreSQL 9.0 and later

PostgreSQL 9.0 added [deferrable unique constraints](http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2009/08/11/waiting-for-8-5-deferrable-uniqueness/), which is exactly the feature you seem to need. This way, uniqueness is checked at commit-time rather than update-time.

Create the UNIQUE constraint with the DEFERRABLE keyword:

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD CONSTRAINT foo_uniq (foo_id) DEFERRABLE;
```

Later, before running the UPDATE statement, you run in the same transaction:

```
SET CONSTRAINTS foo_uniq DEFERRED;
```

Alternatively you can create the constraint with the `INITIALLY DEFERRED` keyword on the unique constraint itself -- so you don't have to run `SET CONSTRAINTS` -- but this might affect the performance of your other queries which don't need to defer the constraint.

### PostgreSQL 8.4 and older

If you only want to use the unique constraint for guaranteeing uniqueness -- not as a target for a foreign key -- then this workaround might help:

First, add a boolean column such as `is_temporary` to the table that temporarily distinguishes updated and non-updated rows:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (value int not null, is_temporary bool not null default false);
```

Next create a **partial unique index** that only affects rows where is_temporary=false:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON foo (value) WHERE is_temporary=false;
```

Now, every time do make the updates you described, you run them in two steps:

```
UPDATE foo SET is_temporary=true, value=value+1 WHERE value>3;
UPDATE foo SET is_temporary=false WHERE is_temporary=true;
```

As long as these statements occur in a single transaction, this will be totally safe -- other sessions will never see the temporary rows. The downside is that you'll be writing the rows twice.

Do note that this is merely a unique index, not a *constraint*, but in practice it shouldn't matter.

Comment: I should have added that I am using Postgres 8.4. So, this does not apply. Still, a point for you.

Comment: In 8.4 you could also work around this by adding another column to the unique constraint -- which distinguishes non-updated and already-updated rows. Unfortunately this also means that it doesn't really guarantee uniqueness anymore. If that doesn't work for you, short of dropping the constraint, 9.0 is the only option.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about adding another column, but it is almost the same as having no constraint at all. Now, I am trying to make up some solution with **recursive with**.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a new idea, based on a partial unique index.

Comment: I am greatly sorry for such a late response, but I did not have access to my database for a while. However, your solution works perfectly. Hence, I accept your answer. Thank you once more for your time and help.

Answer (score 8):

You can do it in 2 queries with a simple trick :

First, update your column with +1, but add a with a x(-1) factor :

```
update my_table set A=(A+1)*-1  where A > 3.
```

You will swtich from 4,5,6 to -5,-6,-7

Second, convert back the operation to restore positive :

```
update my_table set A=(A)*-1  where A < 0.
```

You will have : 5,6,7

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a loop. I don't like this solution, but it works:

```
CREATE TABLE update_unique (id INT NOT NULL);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ux_id ON update_unique (id);
INSERT INTO update_unique(id) SELECT a FROM generate_series(1,100) AS foo(a);

DO $$
DECLARE v INT;
BEGIN
  FOR v IN SELECT id FROM update_unique WHERE id > 3 ORDER BY id DESC 
  LOOP
    UPDATE update_unique SET id = id + 1 WHERE id = v;
  END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

In PostgreSQL 8.4, you might have to create a function to do this since you can't arbitrarily run PL/PGSQL from a prompt using DO (at least not to the best of my recollection).

Comment: This would solve the problem of updating, but the question was whether it is possible to be done with **one query** , i.e., in sole SQL (no PL/PGSQL).